# How to disable same site policy in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-flags

Is it possible to run chrome without checking SameSite attribute even if the server set it

```
Set-Cookie: key=value; SameSite=Strict
```

I did not find any [flag](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Answer (score 7):

Applicable for Chrome version 84 and above

1. Go to chrome://flags/
2. Filter with "SameSite"
3. Disable all 3 flags
4. Refresh browser

[image]

Reference: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug

Comment: Make sure to RESTART the browser for this setting to take effect!

Comment: This setting doesnt seem to exist anymore in version 91

Comment: Solution for Chrome 91<= version < 94: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67782159

Answer (score 0):

From what i have read up about it, i don't believe its normally best practise to do this.

however you might find you answer on [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58344364/setting-google-tag-manager-cookies-with-samesite-and-secure-attributes)

Comment: It needs only for testing. For example chrome has flag to disable origin policy(--disable-web-security), and I expected it to has the same for site policy

Answer (score -1):

You can disable them through chrome://flags Cookie Deprecation messages disabled.

[Look at this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swZEo.png)

your website visitors can still see it. However I don't think you should disable it. rather fix the problem. if you are a developer/owner for the site.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you for helping, but this flag disable only warning, but does not change browser behaviour. About backend solution, it is not secured to disable SameSite in public assembly. We can disable Same site in test assembly, but there are another specific to us cases, which this solution can't resolve.