# Asp.net WebAPP login with microsoft/azure doesn't work in chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

I'm currently trying to set up the "mircosoft login" - Authentication with Azure. I've downloaded the example project and followed the tutorial ( https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp#how-the-sample-works)

I've also upgraded the .net core version from 2 to 3.1 and made a few changes to get it running (not the best code, I've just using this as a reference) however the Login does work with Microsoft Edge and Firefox but not with chrome. If I try using Chrome I do get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Exception: Correlation failed.
Unknown location

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler<TOptions>.HandleRequestAsync()
```

My Startup.cs looks like this :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;

namespace WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                 options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                 options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapControllerRoute(
                    "default",
                    "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think I did a mistake on configuration since its working for Edge and Firefox but I am unsure why this doesnt work on chrome. Am I missing something?
Chrome version: Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you testing using http (instead of https)? Chrome is a bit more strict with some cookies. If so, you could try to disable this setting (just to check if this is the reason) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59030096/how-to-disable-same-site-policy-in-chrome - it's only a guess because we had some oidc issues on dev pcs due to this.

Comment: Oh wow, it was exactly that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by @Christoph Lütjen's comment, add it as the answer to close the question:

If you test using **http** instead of **https**, disable the following settings:

1. Go to `chrome://flags/`
2. Filter with "SameSite"
3. **Disable** all flags
4. Refresh browser

[image]