# Same-site flags were removed in Chromium 91 - How can I disable them for local development?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, samesite

Previously I could disable the verification of same-site cookie in the chrome://flags using the following flags (pic 1) but it seems that in Chromium 91 they were removed (pic 2).

What can I do to disable this verification?

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I gave up fighting with Chrome over that. I've followed a guide to convert my localhost devserver to HTTPS to mimic completely the behavior of the deployed, production environment instead: https://web.dev/how-to-use-local-https/

Answer (score 10):

there is an temporary solution for this problem
set an commond line in chrome/edge (v91) launch cofing like this:

Windows：open Chrome/edge shortcut's property，add: "--disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies" after Target property

in my pc,it like ** "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies ** finally

then restart your chrome/edge,try again

[image]

Comment: Note that this will no longer work in Chrome 94+. The flags will be removed entirely. See https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

For the local development in chrome 91, we need to edit the cookie **SameSite** attribute and set it as **None**.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Chrome 91 these flags are not needed since it is now a default behavior. It means either this feature(s) must be configurable in settings or non-configurable at all (and this is our case!).

However, there are still [similar **launch feature flags** available up until Chrome 94](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site):

- `SameSiteByDefaultCookies`
- `CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure`

For example, launch command in Linux then would be

```sh
google-chrome --disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure
```

I guess after Chrome 94 one has to just deal with it