# How to resolve cross-site resource for google tag manager on react website

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, google-tag-manager

I write react website and want to use google tagmanager to get analytics and get error about cookie.

I read some of comment about this problem and see it was set on header of server side script.But my code was on S3 that I'm not sure how to do it.

here is an error message

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://www.googletagmanager.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58344364/setting-google-tag-manager-cookies-with-samesite-and-secure-attributes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Google Tag Manager cookies with SameSite and Secure attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58344364/setting-google-tag-manager-cookies-with-samesite-and-secure-attributes)